# How to show existence of matrix $L_\beta^\beta$ such that $\forall v\in V:co_\beta(L(v))=L_\beta^\beta co_b(v)$

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

> Given a linear transformation $L\in\hom_{\mathbb R}(V,V)$, we define $L_\beta^\beta\in\mathbb K^{n\times n}$ as the unique matrix, such that
>   $$
> \forall v\in V:\quad co_\beta(L(v))=L_\beta^\beta co_\beta(v).
> $$

The proof is simple (i.e., the columns of $L_\beta^\beta$ are the coordinate vectors of the images of the basis vectors), however, how do we know a priori that such a matrix exists?

About the notation:

- $\beta$ is the basis for the $n$-dimensional vector space $V$.
- $co_\beta$ is the coordinate mapping with respect to the basis $\beta$

Comment: Please explain your notation.

Comment: @HansEngler done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\beta = \{v_1, v_2, ..., v_n\}$ is a basis, for each $i$, there have to be values $b_{ij}$ such that $$L(v_i) = \sum_{j=1}^n b_{ij}v_j$$

The matrix you are after is $$L_\beta^\beta = \begin{bmatrix}b_{11}& \ldots& b_{1n}\\\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\b_{n1}&\ldots&b_{nn}\end{bmatrix}$$